# I wanna make git bash but my default terminal but I'm getting an error because of another settings inside

Tags: bash, git, sass, settings, liveserver

Im trying to make git bash my main terminal but couldn't because of the sass live server compiler. Here is the code

```
terminal.integrated.profiles.windows":{"Git Bash":{"path":"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"},  },
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash"

{
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
        // This is Default.
        {
            "format": "expanded",
            "extensionName": ".css",
            "savePath": "/css"
        }
    ],
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "powershell.powerShellDefaultVersion": "Windows PowerShell (x86)",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 500
}
```

The error Im getting is `Expected a JSON object, array or literal.`

Comment: Sorry about the title. Its 'I wanna make git bash my default terminal'

Comment: Not sure if it takes 10 rep or whatever, but you *should* be able to edit your own posting to fix any title errors, spellign ptyos, or other mis-steaks. Just click the small word `edit` below the displayed post.

Comment: Do you still get the error message when you provide a JSON object, array or literal?

Comment: this should be tagged `visual-studio-code` since that's the software the OP is asking about. I don't think any of the other tags are relevant apart maybe  `settings`.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code is complaining that its settings file is not valid JSON, which it is indeed not. Try the following:

```json
{
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
        // This is Default.
        {
            "format": "expanded",
            "extensionName": ".css",
            "savePath": "/css"
        }
    ],
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "powershell.powerShellDefaultVersion": "Windows PowerShell (x86)",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 500,
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
      "Git Bash": { 
        "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
      },
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash"
}
```